# Getting null value from firebase

Tags: android, firebase

I am trying to fetch value(mobile number and name) from firebase , all the value is coming in dataSnapshot , but still im getting 'null' value in Object class.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5FTfG.png)

Comment: You are getting null from your class or your nameList is null?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried splitting it up?

```
attendanceList.name = attendanceSnapshot.child("Name").getValue(String.class);
```

Just to see if you get any values like this.

Comment: Thanks a lot sir , i was stuck on it since so long time but , now it worked. But the thing is first value(name , mobile number)i am still getting null, and rest all the value are coming.

Comment: Did my answer work for you or did you do something else? If it worked please mark it as answer, if not what happened if others are in the same situation - If you are still getting null can you try to update the question with new code and how it looks?

Comment: AttendanceList attendanceList=attendanceSnapshot.getValue(AttendanceList.class);

attendanceList.name=attendanceSnapshot.child("Name").getValue(String.class);
attendanceList.mobile=attendanceSnapshot.child("Mobile").getValue(String.class);     , i used this code and got the result. Thanks alot Sir. Ur answer resolved my issue.

Comment: Glad that i could help!